# Почему закрыли мой вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

[сам вопрос собственно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468769/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Я его задал, накидали кнопок удалить. Спасибо insolor, что пояснил за что. Я исправил вопрос. Ранее в нём была просьба описать "методы которые вам помогли", теперь там общеприянтые практики, методы с ссылками на литературу и другие источники. Тем не менее вопрос всё равно закрыли, непонятно почему.

UPD - вот что произошло после написания этого вопроса на мете. Это уже сюр какой-то.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто объясните, вы закрываете и дизаете вопрос, чтобы ресурс сделать лучше, верно? Так если вы преследуете эту идею, вы гораздо больше принесете пользы если объясните в чем причина дизов и закрытия вопроса, чтобы автор понял и в будущем задавал нормальные вопросы и улучшал ресурс. Иначе это нелогично, и вам вероятно стоит разбираться в целесообразности ваших действий.

Кстати в чём смысл минусить закрытый вопрос - тоже загадка

Comment: Опять минус, без объяснения причин, если ты потратил минуту чтобы прочесть, потрать 10 секунд чтобы дать отзыв, иначе зачем вообще минусовать.  Я начинаю понимать почему SO ru в таком состоянии ...

Comment: Подозреваю, дело в том, что вопрос неформатный для SO. Он слишком широкий и всеобъемлющий. SO все-таки не википедия. Есть исключение для [списков литературы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/1984), но не для мастер-классов.

Comment: У стрелки "минуса" есть хинт, он вполне отражает типовые причины. Да и в целом, голоса - это улица с двухсторонних движением - плюсы тоже никто не обязан обосновывать. *"начинаю понимать почему %что-угодно% в таком состоянии ..."* - совершенно неинформативный подход. Касательно вопроса по оптимизации - ИМХО он на грани. Было бы неплохо его оставить, но непонятно в каком виде. Ну а текущая причина закрытия там четко и верно указана.

Comment: мне просто заблокировали возможность задавать вопросы после всего этого цирка, поэтому я и цепляюсь в чем дело

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. По идее, за два минуса и закрытие блокировать бы не должно.. а там уже 5 минусов .. ловите компенсационный плюс. Вопрос отражает стремление разобраться, понятен, и несет пользу. Он не настолько плох, чтобы заслужить 5 минусов.

Comment: кек, впервые вижу, что написавший на мету о несправедливости в минусах или закрытии получил ещё больше минусов :D   Обычно сразу плюсов прилетает гора)) даже удивителньно.

Comment: Ещё интересное, что минусы продолжают лететь без пояснений - интересно , может быть это у кого-то пригорает, и потом последует откат минусов после блокировки мультивода? )

Comment: Я считаю, что вопрос слишком общий даже после правок. Он имеет формулировку вида «расскажите мне чё-нибудь», не описывая конкретную проблему. Если меня никто не переубедит, после завершения конкурса проголосую за закрытие

Comment: Как минимум некоторые похожие вопросы на enSO являются закрытыми: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325301), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653980), [три](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266), [четыре](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110684). Не вижу причин, почему на ruSO должно быть иначе

Comment: «в чём смысл минусить закрытый вопрос» — чтобы Дух сообщества его автоматически удалил через некоторое время. Конкретно этот вопрос я (ещё) не минусовал, но вообще я довольно нередко минусую закрытые вопросы и ответы к ним, чтобы увести их из положительного рейтинга и чтобы Дух прибрал мусор в базе знаний

Comment: Кстати, из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions): «если для ответа на ваш вопрос требуется написать целую книгу или существует множество верных ответов, он, скорее всего, не соответствует формату вопросов и ответов» — этот вопрос подходит под оба этих критерия

Comment: @SpaceResearcher единственный вариант который остался для сохранения вопроса это из него сделать вопрос по литературе, учебным материалам и т.п., ведь трудно поспорить с **andreymal**, доводы против вашего вопроса перевешивают.

Comment: @ΝNL993

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12239/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b6%d0%b5-ruso-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc

Ознакомьтесь пожалуйста. Обратных прецедентов тоже хватает, более того, даже те вопросы что привел andreymal , сообщество очевидно считало полезным, особенно третий. А аргумент про книгу не подходит см. ссылку. Других аргументов тут нет

Comment: В самом деле непонятно, почему вопросы на тему [какими способами находить ошибки в коде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701489/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%a1%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba) являются форматными, а аналогичный вопрос на тему какими способами оптимизировать код вдруг неформатный.

Comment: @andreymal в таком случае нужно закрыть [все эти вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701490/282277). Все они не соответсвуют формату вопросов и ответов.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, эти вопросы и вопросы про учебные ресурсы — неформат. Собственно, в [вопросе про книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683) в комментах уже давно упомянули, что аналогичные вопросы на enSO закрываются