# Как все же ruSO относится к общим теоретическим вопросам?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

[Напомню о чем идет речь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12230/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)

**АРГУМЕНТ1** Итак, вопрос закрыли по причине, что он слишком общий и его необходимо конкретизировать. Изначально вопрос был о "методах которые вам помогли", я согласен, что получилась бы каша и в ней полезности было бы мало. Но позже вопрос стал об общепринятых практиках и методах :

> "Не нужно рассказывать о том, что помогло конкретно вам в вашей узкой
> задаче - только общие методики, желательно с ссылками на литературу
> или другие авторитетные источники."

это цитата из вопроса. **Это говорит о том, что вопрос должен решать большинство случаев, а значит определенно нести пользу.**

**АРГУМЕНТ2** Далее по порядку, вот **список не менее общих вопросов, которые, как мы видим полезны сообществу, и существуют уже долго**:
[Как писать красивый и читаемый код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416644/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[На какие уязвимости проверять сайты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/39575/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-sql-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8-xss-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82)
[Защита от DDOS атак](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-ddos-%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA)
[Как отбивать атаки хакеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663883/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8)
[Какие элементы С являются неподдерживаемыми в С++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35502/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%A1-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%A1)
[Хороший стиль обработки ошибок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/34825/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA)
[Учебные ресурсы с++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1)

Каждый из этих и им подобных вопросов представляет собой сборник опыта других участников ресурса. **В таких вопросах много верных ответов**. **Более того - эти вопросы очень общие. Но, как мы видим, это нормальная практика , вопросы живут и дополняются и полезны многим участникам.**

**АРГУМЕНТ3** [Следующее, на что хочу обратить внимание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) , это **справка ресурса**, в которой написано :

> "Какие вопросы можно задавать?... [Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся]**к реальной
> проблеме, встречающейся на практике, решение которой можно изложить
> кратко в паре абзацев, и которая уникальна для разработки программного
> обеспечения и профессионального администрирования IT систем.**"

этот вопрос явно соответствует данному критерию, **а ответы демонстрируют возможность ответить кратко "в паре абзацев"**.

**АРГУМЕНТ4** Далее, если на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468769/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4) невозможно дать объективный ответ, почему там есть ответы, которые объективно полезны и признаются полезными со стороны сообщества о чем свидетельствует кол-во голосов, кстати многие участники голосовали и за сам вопрос, посмотрите в истории голоса "за", лишь спустя некоторое время и два закрытия кол-во голосов "против" смогло перевесить?

Следующая ситуация с голосами за и против,создается впечатление, что огромная часть участников пользуется ими вообще не по назначению, а ,вероятно, по принципу разбитых окон, более того, мало кто способен аргументировать почему он проголосовал так, а не иначе. Когда вопрос начали минусовать никто даже не объяснил в чём дело. При этом на очевидно неуместные(неграмотные, неверно составленные и т.п.) вопросы новичков ,например, иногда по 3 сообщения в комментариях "а где вы попытались, а что вы хотели и т.п.". Почему вы считаете, что в очевидной ситуации надо написать своё мнение, а в спорной не надо?

**АРГУМЕНТ5** Также приведу цитату из [обсуждения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%85) о закрытии вопросов на Мете :

> Какие вопросы не стоит закрывать? Учитывая сказанное выше, давайте
> рассмотрим, какие вопросы являются тематическими для сообщества. В
> самой общей формулировке можно сказать, что:
> Любой прикладной вопрос по программированию или системному администрированию, на который можно дать однозначно верный ответ, **а
> также вопросы по программированию или системному администрированию,
> читая которые можно быстро обучиться чему-то новому, будут
> тематическими для сообщества.** ... Всеобъемлющие вопросы Рассмотрим
> наиболее крайний вопрос: “Что нужно знать начинающему
> Java-программисту?”. На первый взгляд, ответ на подобный вопрос будет
> либо слишком короткий (например, нужно знать язык), либо слишком
> длинный и от части зависящий от мнения. Но если углубиться в
> рассуждения, то можно заметить, что на подобный вопрос существует
> прекрасный и полезный ответ. Как можно ответить на вопрос “Что нужно
> знать начинающему Java-программисту?” с пользой для сообщества? Данным
> вопросом задастся человек, новы для языка Java. Это может быть как
> новичок (например, студент технического вуза), так и специалист ИТ
> (например, системный администратор или тестировщик, который хочет
> переквалифицироваться в Java-программиста).
>
> Учитывая приведенные выше доводы, можно сказать, что при принятии
> решения о закрытии не следует руководствоваться тем, что вопрос
> “слишком простой” или “слишком общий”, так как по факту любой вопрос
> может быть принят сообществом, если он правильно сформулирован и есть
> как минимум один знаток, готовый на него ответить. Закрывая тему, мы
> говорим автору, что его вопрос не соответствует стандартам форума, что
> нет никого, кто бы мог исправить содержание сообщения, и более того,
> никто не собирается публиковать ответы. На наш взгляд, так стоит
> поступать с теми вопросами, которые нарушают идеологию проекта:
>
> вопросы с просьбами о завершении задач за автора, как учебных, так и
> рабочих;
> слишком локальные вопросы (например, вызванные опечаткой);
> вопросы вида “найди ошибку в моем коде” с условием, что они никак и никому, за исключением автора, не смогут помочь в будущем;
> вопросы-опросники.

**АРГУМЕНТ6** Сообщество даже разрешает задавать конструктивные субъективные вопросы(далее цитата) :

> Все же, некоторые субъективные вопросы допустимы, но «некоторые» не
> подразумевает «любые». Любой, даже субъективный вопрос на сайте должен
> быть конструктивным. Конструктивные субъективные вопросы:
>
> ```
> -предполагают ответы, которые объясняют «почему» и «как»;
> -предполагают развернутые и подробные ответы;
> -имеют конструктивный, честный и непредвзятый характер;
> -подразумевают обмен опытом, а не мнениями;
> -требуют подтверждения изложенного фактами и ссылками;
> -являются чем-то большим, чем просто бессмысленное весёлое общение.
> ```

**Каждый из вышеперечисленных пунктов выполняется [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468769/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4). Исходя из этого вопрос следует переоткрыть**

**Проголосуйте,пожалуйста, за переоткрытие, если вы согласны**

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140991/discussion-on-question-by-space-researcher----ruso----).

Comment: оформил бы цитаты как цитаты, а не как код. Читать невозможно.